# Dojo JSON serialization, using various serialization strategies

Tags: javascript, json, date, serialization, dojo

I have the issue with serializing inputs of DateTextBox and TimeTextBox to JSON - during serialization the timezone convertion is made, which forces me to send timezone to server and do appropriate adaptations there.

To prevent there I'd like to change the date format for serialization purposes. I can alter Date's prototype, as described [here](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/06/14/how-do-you-serialize-dates-from-forms-to-json-with-dojo/) (I've done that in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lechlukasz/Pw9Ew/)), but I'd prefer not to alter the behaviour for the scope of single request. Something like that:

```
 someDojoUtil.jsonSerialize(obj, {option1: 'value1'...})
```

Does Dojo provide the way for achieving it, or the only way is to globally alter Date's prototype?

Comment: Does the toJSON() method (as mentioned in the linked article) not satisfy your need?  For example, in your Form object, attach your specialized toJSON serialization to all Date inputs in that form?  (Thus quarantining the affects to just that form?)

Comment: @bishop I'd like to put the responsibility for the serialization to the method that invokes the REST channel, thus isolating the code for the place where it belongs, and asserting, that other parts of application (possibly using other remote services) are unaffected.

Comment: In the long term I suggest you send *all* date/times over the wire in UTC, in both directions. Isn't that what you're already doing with a Javascript `Date` object gets serialized?

Comment: @Darien the problem is that the client Timezone shift can be arbitrary, so no, I can't do that out-of-the-box withing server. What could be possible is for JavaScript widget to work on UTC, but DoJo's TimeTextBox is working on local time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comment elaboration in OP, I would use the second argument to Json.stringify, the so-called "replacer".  Something like this:

```
require(['dojo/json'], function(Json) {
    function replacer(key, value) {
        if ('string' === typeof (value)) {
            var d = new Date(value);
            if (isNaN(d.getTime())) {
                return value; // string, but not a date
            }

            // do whatever you want to do, this is just an example
            d.setSeconds(0);

            return d.toJSON();
        }
        return value;
    }
    var data = {'a':new Date(), 'b':123, 'c':'foo', 'd':[new Date()]};
    var str = Json.stringify(data, replacer);
    console.log(str);
});
```

I suggest writing this as a mixin for dojo/request, then creating yourself a custom request class that has this behavior, then using that custom request object as needed.

This feels hackish, but I think it will meet your need (as I'm understanding it!).

Comment: Yes, very hacky. It wouldn't hacky if dojo had given the object before stringify to the replacer. Anyway, it's the solution I can consider as alternative to altering prototype.

Comment: @ŁukaszL: To be fair to Dojo, it's just passing along to the native [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), which behaves this way as well.  The whole object is available, but not during the iteration.  `JSON.stringify({a:new Date()}, function (k,v) { console.log(v); return v; })` to see what I mean.  Glad this worked for you!